# How to fix "No such file or directory" after selecting a file from Android?

Tags: android, file, kotlin

I am trying to select a file(csv file) form android device. It works fine in emulator. But, when I test in real device, however I select a csv file it keeps showing "No such file or directory". I don't get it why it doesn't work on real device. I already added permission in manifests. Here is the code

```
    db=DataBaseHelper(this)
     lbl=EditText(this)
     lbl=view.findViewById(R.id.edit_master)
     noti = lbl.text.toString()
     btnimport=view.findViewById(R.id.img_import)
     btnimport.setOnClickListener {
         val fileintent=Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
         fileintent.type="text/csv"
         try {
             startActivityForResult(fileintent, requestcode)
         } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
             lbl.text="No activity can handle picking a file. Showing alternatives."
         }
     }
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (data == null)
        return
    if (requestCode<=requestcode) {
        val filepath=data.data!!.path
        println(filepath)
        lbl.text = filepath
        val inputStream=FileInputStream(filepath)
        println(inputStream)
        val bb=db.writableDatabase
        val myPath = DB_PATH + REAL_DATABASE
        val db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
        val tableName="Master"
        db.execSQL("delete from $tableName")
        try {
            println("gg")
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    val file=InputStreamReader(inputStream)

                    val buffer=BufferedReader(file)
                    buffer.readLine()
                    val contentValues=ContentValues()
                    db.beginTransaction()
                    while(true) {
                        val line=buffer.readLine()
                        if (line == null) break
                        val str=line.split(",".toRegex(), 3)
                            .toTypedArray()

                        val _id1=str[0].toString()
                        val quantity1=str[1].toString()
                        val name=str[2].toString()

                        contentValues.put("_id1", _id1)
                        contentValues.put("quantity1", quantity1)
                        contentValues.put("name", name)
                        db.insert(tableName, null, contentValues)

                    }

                    db.setTransactionSuccessful()
                    db.endTransaction()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    if (db.inTransaction())
                        db.endTransaction()
                    val d=Dialog(this)
                    d.setTitle(e.message.toString() + "first")
                    d.show()
                }

            } else {
                if (db.inTransaction())
                    db.endTransaction()
                val d=Dialog(this)
                d.setTitle("Only CSV files allowed")
                d.show()
            }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            if (db.inTransaction())
                db.endTransaction()

            val d=Dialog(this)
            d.setTitle(ex.message.toString() + "second")
            d.show()
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `val filepath=data.data!!.path` is wrong - it does not point to any existing path - simply use `data.data` and `ContentResolver` to get the `InputStream` for reading

Comment: But it worked on emulator, what is the difference?

Comment: ok what is `filepath` in your case? tried to `Log.d` that value? if so, what do you see on the logcat?

Comment: It shows the path I chose "/root/storage/emulated/0/Download/original.csv".

Comment: and what do you see if you execute `adb shell ls -l /root/storage/emulated/0/Download/original.csv` command?

Comment: It says no such file or directory

Comment: then read [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html) why it is so

Comment: Ahh, got it . Well if that's the case, I will try again as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally as "pskink" suggested , I changed my code from this,

```
val filepath=data.data!!.path
    val inputStream=FileInputStream(filepath)
```

to this

```
val filepath=data.data
val inputstream= contentResolver.openInputStream(android.net.Uri.parse(filepath.toString()))
```

and the result is beautiful :)

Comment: I didn't under stand why if somebody can explain i'll be thankful